# Using full words as variables for login system

Tags: java, integer

I'm creating a login system that currently uses hard coded integers for a UserID, password and Student number which means they are all numbers. What would I use to be able to make the integers (the UserID and password) words instead of numbers? This is how it currently looks;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int UserID = 5555; 
    final int Password = 1234;
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What about student number 998238123812389? Won't fit in `int`.

Comment: final String UserID = "5555"?

Comment: What does the rest of the code do? you might need a lot of changes there too.

Comment: are you looking for String maybe?

Comment: If they put a zero at the start of their number-string, it will be stripped away when converting to an int, meaning their username or password will be different than they expect, and they'll be locked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    final int UserID = 5555; 
    final int Password = 1234;
    final int StudentNumber = 22334455;
String UserID_str = String.valueOf(UserID);
String Password_str = String.valueOf(Password);
String StudentNumber_str = String.valueOf(StudentNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert integers to Strings you can use [.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

```
final String UserID = new Integer(5555).toString(); 
final String Password = new Integer(1234).toString();
final String StudentNumber = new Integer(22334455).toString();
```